# How to loop through Object and create a tree Object

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I have a flat object and an array from which I need to construct a tree-like object.

```
choices: ['choice1', 'choice2', 'choice3'];
items: [
    {
        choice1: 'taste',
        choice2: 'good',
        choice3: 'green-lemon'
    },
    {
        choice1: 'taste',
        choice2: 'bad',
        choice3: 'green-lemon'
    }
];
```

The array describes the level at which each choice will come in the tree. I do not know how many choices, items or levels there will be later.

How do I get the following object:

```
output: {
    taste: {
        good: {
            green-lemon:1
        },
        bad: {
            green-lemon:1
        }
    }
}
```

I need to get an object describing how many items there are on each level. In this example this is `choice1: 1;` `choice2: 2` and each `choice3: 1`.

Any advice on how to build a loop to get this result?

Comment: Are there going to be more levels than this? Will this data set ever expand?

Comment: Is the `choices` array meant to describe the level at which each choice comes in the tree? @brainwipe's question is also relevant to a correct solution.

Comment: @brainwipe: There might be only 2 levels of choices and there might be 5 levels of choices. The choices array and the items object will never change during runtime.

Comment: @JordanGray: items contains more data. The choices array describes the tree as level0 would be the first item and the last level  the last item.

Comment: @ProtoBassi That's helpful. Do you want to come out with the tree, the item count or both as the result of the array?

Comment: @JordanGray: the tree. The last leaf (here: green-lemmon) does not matter (could be an empty object itself). The last leaf will be only reused later to calc the number of last leaves in the tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best solution here is a loop with some recursion. I have increased the size of the model in the example to show it going with n levels. Check the output with your javascript console.

```
var choices = ['choice1', 'choice2', 'choice3'];
var items = [{
    choice1: 'taste',
    choice2: 'good',
    choice3: 'green-lemon'
}, {
    choice1: 'taste',
    choice2: 'bad',
    choice3: 'green-lemon'
},
{
    choice1: 'taste',
    choice2: 'ok',
    choice3: 'green-lemon'
},
{
    choice1: 'taste',
    choice2: 'ok',
    choice3: 'green-lemon'
}];

function IsLastLevel(levelIndex) {
    return (levelIndex == choices.length - 1);
}

function HandleLevel(currentItem, currentLevel, nextChoiceIndex) {

    var nextLevelName = currentItem[choices[nextChoiceIndex]];

    if (typeof currentLevel[nextLevelName] === 'undefined') {
        currentLevel[nextLevelName] = {};
    }

    if (IsLastLevel(nextChoiceIndex)) {
        if (currentLevel[nextLevelName] > 0) {
            currentLevel[nextLevelName]++;
        } else {
            currentLevel[nextLevelName] = 1;
        }
    } else {
        var goOneDeeper = nextChoiceIndex + 1;
        HandleLevel(currentItem, currentLevel[nextLevelName], goOneDeeper);
    }
}

var output = {};

for(var itemIndex in items)
{
    var item = items[itemIndex];
    HandleLevel(item, output, 0);
}

console.log(output);
```

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brainwipe/vhWx5/4/)

Answer (score 2):

Brainwipe has already given a very clean answer, but I thought I would try my hand anyway. This solution works by recursively reducing the list of items, level by level, until it reaches the leaf nodes.

```js
function choiceTree(items, choices) {
    // Return empty object if there were no choices.
    if (!choices.length) return {};

    var choice = choices.shift();

    // Construct the current level of the tree.
    var level = items.reduce(function(node, item) {
        var value = item[choice];

        // Add item if branch node or set to 1 if leaf node.
        node[value] = (choices.length)
            ? (node[value] || []).concat(item)
            : 1;

        return node;
    }, {});

    // Return if there are no remaining choices.
    if (!choices.length) return level;

    // Recursively construct the next level.
    for (var node in level)
        level[node] = choiceTree(level[node], choices.slice());

    return level;
}
```

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jordan/pPwa5/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, too. It is way less code, but harder to read. I have not worked with reduce yet, but will definately take a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: `Array.reduce` is really cool and underused, you should definitely read up on it! :) All it does is "reduce" an array to a single value; you could [use a `for` loop instead](http://jsfiddle.net/Jordan/j5aXL/), but I think the extra code is messier. It's not supported in IE 8 and below, but it's [easy to shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Compatibility).